# How to loop through shapes (oval1, oval2, oval3...)?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2010

I've stumbled upon this code to loop through textboxes, and it's what I need, except I need to do it for ovals (Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 29; i++)
{
   TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Controls["textBox" + i];
}
```

So it would probably look like

```
for (int i = 1; i < 29; i++)
{
   Shape oval = (Shape)???["oval" + i]
   oval.FillColor = blue;
}
```

I just don't know what the "Controls" counterpart is for shapes. I don't know if this code will work, so please tell me if there's another way to do this.

Comment: @GrawCube All the shapes are just ovals with similar names (oval1, oval2 ,oval3, etc). They are stored in ShapeContainers

Comment: @GrawCube Yes I have multiple shape containers and each contain 4 ovals. Each container is in a Panel (I'm guessing this is a form control?)

Comment: You can have a List<Panel> or you can create a class Shape and then have a List<Shape>. The latter is more extensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can typically use LINQ to select a certain type of control inside of a collection, in this case `Controls` and `ShapeContainer`, by using [`OfType<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
var ovals = Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>()
                    .SelectMany(sc => sc.Controls.OfType<OvalShape>());

foreach (var oval in ovals)
{
    oval.FillColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

As GrawCube pointed out, the `ShapeContainer` has its own property for accessing its shapes, appropriately named [Shapes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecontainer.shapes.aspx). You may have to use this instead:

```
var ovals = Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>()
                    .SelectMany(sc => sc.Shapes.OfType<OvalShape>());
```

Given that some ShapeContainers are inside Panels, and others are not, the query gets a little uglier but not too bad. First we search the main Controls collection, then search all the child Panels, and concatenate the results.

```
var ovals = Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>()
                .SelectMany(sc => sc.Shapes.OfType<OvalShape>())
                .Concat(Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                    .SelectMany(p => p.Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>()
                        .SelectMany(sc => sc.Shapes.OfType<OvalShape>())));
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much to the both of you, the second code worked!

Comment: Oh, but it only worked for shapecontainer1. Is it possible for it to extend to the others? I have 8.

Comment: @GrantWinney Ah yes sorry, didn't specify. The other ShapeContainers are nested in panels. They are actually the ones that need color.

Comment: @GrantWinney exactly. The ShapeContainer this code affected was the one outside of any panel.